# Forking in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, daemon, fork

I'm a little bit confused as to how to create daemons in NodeJS

I've created daemons in C before that call `fork()` that continue execution from where the call was made in a child process allowing the parent to terminate. I can't readily achieve the same affect using `process.fork()` and `process.kill()`.

The following code doesn't do what I expected and breaks:

```
var current_pid, cp = require('child_process');
current_pid = process.pid;
cp.fork('');
process.kill(current_pid);
```

The following error is emitted and I can't work out why or what's happening:

```
node.js:202
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: read EBADF
    at errnoException (net.js:589:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:335:20)
```

The problem call appears to be `process.kill()`. Removing this, both processes continue to happily run.

I'm aware of [daemon.node](https://github.com/Slashed/daemon.node), but this was created at the time when `child_process.fork()` didn't exist (v0.1.33 was the version available when daemon.node was written). Now there is a native way to fork, so this should no longer be necessary. (Plus, it appears to have been abandoned too.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`child_process.fork()` has a **totally misleading name** and is not the same as C’s `fork()`.

[According to the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options), it executes a Node.js script as a child process and sets up a communications channel between the calling process and the child. That's it.

The actual spawning of the child process [is done inside libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/src/unix/process.c), Node's “platform layer,” in C, and `fork()` itself is not exposed to Node scripts.

A simple, much-improvable way to daemonize using only what’s built-in to Node.js might look like this:

```
if (process.argv[2] !== 'child') {
    require('child_process').execFile(process.argv[0], [__filename, 'child']);
    process.exit();
}

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('foo');
}, 5000);
```

Obviously, this is pretty different from `fork()`. If daemon.node works for you, keep using it.

Answer (score 2):

daemon.node continues to be developed at https://github.com/indexzero/daemon.node.